# What is the type of sum?

Tags: python, types, python-3.11

I want to express that the first parameter is a "list" of the second parameter, and that the result has the same type as the second parameter.

This `mysum` (ie. not the standard lib `sum`) should work equally well with int/float/str/list, and any other type that supports `+=`.

Naively:

```
def mysum(lst: list[T], start: T) -> T:
    x = start
    for item in lst:
        x += item
    return x
```

which produces:

```
(dev311) go|c:\srv\tmp> mypy sumtype.py
sumtype.py:26: error: Unsupported left operand type for + ("T")
sumtype.py:35: error: Cannot infer type argument 1 of "mysum"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Second attempt:

```
from typing import Iterable, Protocol, TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T')

class Addable(Protocol[T]):
    def __add__(self, other: T) -> T:
        ...

class RAddable(Protocol[T]):
    def __radd__(self, other: T) -> T:
        ...

def mysum(lst: Iterable[Addable|RAddable], start: Addable) -> Addable:
    x = start
    for item in lst:
        x += item
    return x
```

however, this doesn't place any restrictions on the "list" items and start being the same type, so this typechecks:

```
class Foo:
    def __radd__(self, other: int) -> int:
        return other + 42


mysum([Foo()], [])  # <=== should ideally fail since Foo() and [] are not the same type
```

and fails with a type-error at runtime:

```
(dev311) go|c:\srv\tmp> python sumtype.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\srv\tmp\sumtype.py", line 27, in <module>
    mysum([Foo()], [])
  File "c:\srv\tmp\sumtype.py", line 18, in mysum
    x += item
  File "c:\srv\tmp\sumtype.py", line 24, in __radd__
    return other + 42
           ~~~~~~^~~~
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

I'm assuming it can't be this difficult to type-annotate a generic function, so what am I missing..?

Comment: I can't understand how the title of this question is intended to describe the actual question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a generic type [bound](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) to a protocol that supports `__add__` instead:

> Type variables can be bound to concrete types, abstract types (ABCs or
> **protocols**), and even unions of types

```
from typing import TypeVar, Protocol

T = TypeVar('T', bound='Addable')

class Addable(Protocol):
    def __add__(self: T, other: T) -> T:
        ...

def mysum(lst: list[T], start: T) -> T:
    x = start
    for item in lst:
        x += item
    return x
```

Demo: https://mypy-play.net/?gist=ecf4031f21fb81e75d6e6f75d16f3911

Comment: Your demo throws an error on line 16.

Comment: That's the whole point of the demo. It passes the static type check on line 15 and properly fails the type check on line 16, where argument 1 has a mismatching type with argument 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to pass type argument to `(R)Addable` in your second attempt.

```py
from typing import Iterable, Protocol, TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T')

class Addable(Protocol[T]):
    def __add__(self: T, other: T) -> T:
        ...

class RAddable(Protocol[T]):
    def __radd__(self: T, other: T) -> T:
        ...

def mysum(lst: Iterable[Addable[T]|RAddable[T]], start: Addable[T]) -> T:
    x = start
    for item in lst:
        x += item
    return x
```

But this won't work either. Using bounded TypeVar suggested by @blhsing is more elegant and intuitive than this.

The only working example in mypy I can get without bound TypeVar:

```py
from typing import Iterable, Protocol, TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T')

class Addable(Protocol[T]):
    def __add__(self: T, other: T) -> T: ...

def mysum(lst: Iterable[Addable[T]], start: T) -> T:
    x = start
    for item in lst:
        x = item + x
    return x

print(mysum(['a'], 'b'))
```

`str` is not `RAddable[T]` in `mypy`, `int` is ok:

```py
from typing import Iterable, Protocol, TypeVar
T = TypeVar('T')

class RAddable(Protocol[T]):
    def __radd__(self: T, other: T) -> T: ...

def mysum(lst: Iterable[RAddable[T]], start: T) -> T:
    x = start
    for item in lst:
        x += item
    return x

print(mysum([1], 2))
```